# How do you add elements in a row based on another rows attribute?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, scripting

I have a multidimensional array. The last column [6] is denoted by either just a 1 or a 0. I'm trying to write an if statement to add the numbers in column 4 that have 0 and the numbers that have 1 separately. I only get a return value of 0 for both.

```
with open(filePath + fileName, 'rt')  as inputfile2:
    next(inputfile2)
    dataArray = csv.reader(inputfile2, delimiter='\t')
    for row in dataArray:
        if (row[6] == 1):
            sumNSal =+ int(row[4])
        if (row[6] ==0):
            sumNSalR =+ int(row[4])
    print sumNSal, sumNSalR
```

Comment: Are you sure that column 4 is ints not strings from the csv?

Comment: yes, just values

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you're using `=+` instead of `+=`

Comment: And you probably tried printing the rows to make sure that the results of `csv.reader(inputfile2, delimiter='\t')` are exactly what you were expecting them to be?

Comment: If you want to put the inputfile2 file on Dropbox or something I could look at it -- otherwise, at this point it's hard to say more without actually seeing the data.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could make a free account on https://www.dropbox.com/ or other file-sharing service, upload the file, and then share a link to the file.